# Can't visualise time series correctly in Python

Tags: pandas, plot, time, series

I have a problem visualising time series in the format D/M/Y h/m/s

The following code works for the first day and produces incorrect output after that.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cars = pd.read_csv('time_series.csv', parse_dates=['Ldatetime'], index_col='Ldatetime')
cars.plot()
```

[image]

Here is the data format:

[image]

If I remove the data parser, the plot looks fine but it's not recognised as time.

[image]

Comment: The visualization is correct. You have no data for the rows in between the seventh and 12th of july so it draws a straight line

Comment: The data is visualised correctly if I remove the data parser - done in the second plot.  Also, If I visualise with the parser only the first day, it works fine.  It only  breaks after the end of day 1.

Comment: In the second plot it disregards relative distances between dates and every row is a new increment as it takes the row index, which is linearly increasing. Thus the data is not distorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you provided contains days in December as well as June:

```
date,car
2023-12-06 23:20:00,12
2023-12-06 23:25:00,19
2023-12-06 23:30:00,10
2023-12-06 23:35:00,13
2023-12-06 23:40:00,13
2023-12-06 23:45:00,15
2023-12-06 23:50:00,14
2023-12-06 23:55:00,9
2023-06-13 00:00:00,5
2023-06-13 00:05:00,4
2023-06-13 00:10:00,7
2023-06-13 00:15:00,6
2023-06-13 00:20:00,7
2023-06-13 00:25:00,7
2023-06-13 00:30:00,4
```

some of them are `06-13` and some of them are `12-06`
The visualizations are correct.

Comment: This is the data where my plot fails:

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is part of the data, where my plot fails. I have inspected the file and there is nothing wrong with the data that I can see.                                                                                  
2023-12-06 23:20:00 12
2023-12-06 23:25:00 19
2023-12-06 23:30:00 10
2023-12-06 23:35:00 13
2023-12-06 23:40:00 13
2023-12-06 23:45:00 15
2023-12-06 23:50:00 14
2023-12-06 23:55:00 9
2023-06-13 00:00:00 5
2023-06-13 00:05:00 4
2023-06-13 00:10:00 7
2023-06-13 00:15:00 6
2023-06-13 00:20:00 7
2023-06-13 00:25:00 7
2023-06-13 00:30:00 4

Comment: your data is wrong...

Comment: Yes, I just spotted that, thank you. The original data was fine but it looks like the problem appeared when I used pd.to_datetime for the time column. It has switched the place of month and date for everything after the first day so it looks like there is a gap. I'll close this and open another question if I can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: I think closing the question would be good. I voted to close, then retracted and now i can't close again. "Was produced by a typo or is not reproducible" I'll be glad to take a look at the thing again. I learned about `parse_date` in the course of this and iso-8061 :)

Comment: Just for completeness - the problem was that the parameter dayfirst=True should have been used when applying to_datetime on the time column. If not, it would swap the place of date and month for part of the data, creating the gap. This is the correct command to load the  data                                                                                           
 cars = pd.read_csv('time_series.csv')
cars['Local Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(cars['Local Datetime'], dayfirst=True)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, it's generally appreciated on the platform!